# Unable to use 3rd party static library because of wrong export macro

Tags: c++, visual-studio, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I am using an open source [library](https://computation.llnl.gov/projects/sundials/sundials-software) on windows. The library compiles to a shared version (dll-files) and a static version. Thus far I have successfully used the shared version, but now I want to use the static one instead.

The problem is that the preprocessor always seems to configure the header files for dll-import which causes linker errors because the functions are not found in the corresponding static lib-file. Searching for the relevant export macro definition in the header files, I have only found this single occurrence

```
/* Mark SUNDIALS API functions for export/import
 * When building shared SUNDIALS libraries under Windows, use
 *      #define SUNDIALS_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
 * When linking to shared SUNDIALS libraries under Windows, use
 *      #define SUNDIALS_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
 * In all other cases (other platforms or static libraries under
 * Windows), the SUNDIALS_EXPORT macro is empty
 */
#ifdef BUILD_SUNDIALS_LIBRARY
#define SUNDIALS_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define SUNDIALS_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

According to my interpretation of the above, SUNDIALS_EXPORT can never be empty (as opposed to what the comment tells us), and so the static version library can never be used successfully. I have confirmed this by temporarily just replacing the #ifdef block by

```
#define SUNDIALS_EXPORT
```

because then I can use the static library and my code compiles. So now I could just introduce another #define like SUNDIALS_USE_STATIC_LIBRARY_VERSION to condition the above preprocessor block, but before changing 3rd party code **I wonder if this is really a bug or if I might have missed something about the designated mechanism for using the static library.**

What is interesting is the fact, that the same #ifdef block is also used during the build process of the static library. So I suppose that the wrong declspec must have been ignored somehow during the build of the static library (because the generation of static library succeeded). **I wonder then if the declspec can also be ignored when I use the static library in my own project.**

The only difference between the static and the shared build project seems to be the definition of the inherited _WINDLL macro.

Comment: The only way to not define the preprocessor symbol `SUNDIALS_EXPORT` would be to not include the file that defines it. I don't know if you have any control over this, or whether building a static library is supported (and verified to work) at all.

Comment: The file (sundials_config.h) is used in many other headers, so then it would be easier to just change the file itself than changing all its occurrences. Formally the static library projects are the result of a cmake, so they are supported but probably not tested on windows. What indicates the latter is: the static lib-files get overwritten during ALL_BUILD by the shared lib-files because of the same name (a problem that does not occur on *IX-OSes where shared is *.so and static is *.a). I have to compile the static ones separately to catch them.

Comment: Isn't it possible to somehow redefine "sundials_config.h" to "sundials_static_config.h" with the preprocessor or is this asking for trouble? If it's possible I could heal the problem in my own project without explicitely changing 3rd party code.

Comment: If that is the case, then that would warrant submitting a bug report to the owner of the library. As you say, changing 3rd party code is not feasible, and potentially in violation with the library's license. To my knowledge, redirecting include files isn't possible. What can be done, though, would be to create your custom "sundials_config.h" for your static library, move that to some directory, and add that directory to the front of include directories for the static library project(s). That, too, could violate the library license, but at least you aren't modifying library code.

Comment: @IInspectable: that did the trick! Thank you so much! I think the license is not an issue in this case because it's BSD.

Comment: How did you get it to compile correctly. I got so far as to create the DLLs, but I am unable to reference them in my other projects due to the 'could not be added' error.

Comment: @JasonSmith: are you referring to SUNDIALS specifically?  I am using it from C# client projects, where I can just define the name/signature of the function and the calling convention - no need for def-files and such. So if you are using the library from C++ then I'm afraid I can't help (other than that it must be possible to get it working somehow).

Comment: @oliver Thank you for the reply. I have downloaded and extracted the files for Sundials and then used CMAKE to create the VS projects. I have been following the instructions included with the downloaded PDF, but have not been able to compile Sundials into the DLLs correctly.

Comment: @JasonSmith: all I remember is that it took me a while to understand what CMAKE expects me to do. I am not so acquainted with how the open source guys build projects, so I am glad it worked for me, but I am certainly the worst person to help you. My advice: carefully check the options CMAKE offers you, most are irrelevant, but some have to be changed. I am really not sure, but I guess it was something with filesystem paths, and probably something with parallelism/CUDA where I removed the checkmarks?

Comment: @oliver Thank you for the feedback. I will give it a shot! I also have no experience with CMAKE, so I agree -- my issue was likely related to CMAKE configuration.